# Apk not detect an obb unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I didn't find any clear documentation on obb, so I decided to contact here. In general, the apk does not detect an obb file on android. The file is located in the right directory, the apk itself runs normally.
As far as I understand, I don't need to do anything extra with obb in the code and just put it in obb/packagename. Maybe I'm wrong, so I really look forward to your help

upd. Maybe I need to do something in the code? I just put the obb in the right directory and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the trick:

step 1. create a folder as same as package name

step 2. copy the obb file into that folder

step 3. rename the obb file to main.BundleVersionCode.packagename.obb

step 4. copy the folder to your Android Phone directory: Android/obb/, or try to copy the folder to sdcard/Android/obb/ if you have external sd card.

Then now you should be able to install the apk.